# Problem with ExtJs editor grid panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I've an extjs editor grid panel(3.3.1) that is binded to a store. New records are added to the grid by an empty row at the top. On the load of the store I'm adding an empty row at the top of the grids. When the user adds a new value and the focus loses out I'm adding another empty row.

```
AV.ClassifiedCategories = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
   ....

initComponent: function(){  

    this.store = this.initialConfig.store;

            //add an empty row at top
    this.store.on('load', this.addCategory, this);

            Ext.apply(this, 
    {
        clicksToEdit: 1,            
        listeners:
        {
        afteredit : function(e){
                 this.addCategory();                        
        },
        scope: this
        }
    });
    },

    //adds an empty row and insert a record to store
    addCategory: function(){
    var Category = this.getStore().recordType;
    var cat = new Category({ cat_id: null, cat_name: "" });     

    this.stopEditing();     
    this.store.insert(0, cat);  
    this.startEditing(0, 0);

    return cat;
},

    ...
});
```

The problem is facing here is once the afteredit event is fired and an empty row is added the focus is not moving to the first row i.e. the second row is still in edit mode. How I can solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your code and have created [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/vyaev/). As you can see everything works as expected. Are you sure you have provided us with non-working code?

Comment: I really appreciate for taking the time to try that out. You are absolutely right there is no problem with the posted code but it is created by another code and I fixed that. Thanks.